Add a legend to a voronoi diagram with field values
I try to create a map with a voronoi diagram of some climate stations. I've already created the diagram and also colored the areas in the diagram with a fitting color. Now I want a continuous legend that tells me what the colors in the areas mean.
This is what already works so far:
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
e <- vect(f)
x <- centroids(e)
v <- voronoi(x, e)
v <- terra::crop(v, e)

FUN <- colorRamp(c("black", "lightgrey"))
vpop <- (v$POP - min(v$POP)) / diff(range(v$POP))
vcols <- rgb(FUN(vpop), maxColorValue = 256)

plot(v, lwd = 2, col = vcols, 
     main = "Voronoi Diagram", 
     background = "beige"
     )
points(x, col = "red")


I want a legend on the right side or on the bottom side of the plot, that matches the population numbers of the areas with the colors used in there. Since the original data has 50 Points, I want a continuous legend.
This is what I've tried:
l <- c(5.8, 6.4, 49.35, 49.38)

plot(v, lwd = 2, col = vcols, 
     main = "Voronoi Diagram", 
     background = "beige",
     type = "continuous",
     range = c(min(v$POP, max(v$POP)))
     plg = list(
       ext = l,
       loc = "bottom",
       title = "Population"
       )
     )
points(x, col = "red")

I've also tried moving type and range into the list of the plg argument, but it also had no result.
I've also tried using the add_legend function from terra.
add_legend("right",
           legend = c(min(v$POP), max(v$POP)),
           col = vcols)

Which also only results in two numbers floating in the map.

This is unrelated to the great answer below, but you might find yourself circling back to plotting anomalies that may frustrate. Minor and random, but main = "Voronoi Diagram" becomes "Voronoi" upon your plotted. A head scratch. capabilities() will tell you which graphics devices you have access to and their specific(s), say X11.options(). This question prompted me to finally switch in .Rprofile from Xlib to cairo, This may be inapplicable depending on your OS but you have an indicator of further issues.

@Chris Thanks for recognizing, that is really impressive. I actually found the error during editing my question in stack overflow and forgot to update the graphic. So mistake is by me. I will edit the post and upload the correct plot.

You just need to add the name of the attribute you wish to plot as the y argument to plot and set the type = "continuous".
# Need to order the values to get the color ramp in the correct order.
vpop <- vpop[order(vpop)]
vcols <- rgb(FUN(vpop), maxColorValue = 256)

plot(v, 
     "POP",
     lwd = 2, 
     type = "continuous",
     col = vcols, 
     main = "Voronoi Diagram", 
     background = "beige",
)
points(x, col = "red")



Maybe something like this:
library(terra)

f <- system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra")
e <- vect(f)
x <- centroids(e)
v <- voronoi(x, e)
v <- terra::crop(v, e)

r <- rast(v, ncols=6000, nrows=8000)
z <- rasterize(v, r, field = "POP")



FUN <- colorRamp(c("black", "lightgrey"))
vpop <- (v$POP - min(v$POP)) / diff(range(v$POP))
vcols <- rgb(FUN(vpop), maxColorValue = 256)
vcols_sorted <- rgb(FUN(sort(vpop)), maxColorValue = 256)

layout(matrix(1:2, nrow=2), width = c(1,1), height = c(5,1))
plot(v, lwd = 2, col = vcols, 
     main = "Voronoi Diagram", 
     background = "beige"
)
points(x, col = "red")

legend_image <- as.raster(matrix(vcols_sorted, nrow=1))
plot(c(0,0.5), c(0,0.5), type = 'n', 
     axes = F, xlab = '', ylab = '', main = 'Population')
text(y=-1.2, x = seq(0.15, 0.35, l =3), 
     labels = c("5,000", "95,000", "185,000"))
rasterImage(legend_image, 0.15, 0, 0.35, 1.5)


See this question for more details: Gradient legend in base
